# How to hide an inflated layout when clicked outside in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have 3 layouts:

1. Main Layout
2. 1st fragment (1st screen of View Pager under Main Layout)
3. SwipeUpView (Inflated layout by swipe up action)

The question is, how do I dismiss/close the SwipeUp layout when I click outside of it when the 1st fragment is also a clickable layout which opens another activity.

*Note: the SwipeUp Layout only takes 1/4 of the screen that is why I can be able to click out).

```java
bottomDraggerView.setOnTouchListener(object:View.OnTouchListener

    {
        override fun onTouch(p0:View ?, p1:MotionEvent ?):Boolean {

        when(p1 ?.action)
        {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN->{
            startPoint = p1.rawY
        }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ->{
            val moveY = Math.max(0.0f, p1.rawY + startPoint) + height
            swipeUpView.y = moveY
        }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ->{

            val diff = Math.abs(startPoint + p1.rawY)
            var finalPosition :Float
            if (diff > height / 2) {
                finalPosition = 0.0f + 270
            } else {
                finalPosition = 0.0f - height
            }

            swipeUpView.animate().y(finalPosition).setDuration(400).start()
            Log.d("Swipe", "value " + finalPosition.toString())
        }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL ->{
            val diff = Math.abs(startPoint + p1.rawY)
            var finalPosition :Float
            if (diff > height / 2) {
                finalPosition = 0.0f - 400
            } else {
                finalPosition = 0.0f
            }

            swipeUpView.animate().y(finalPosition).setDuration(400).start()

        }
        }
        return true
    }

    })
```

What I want is that if SwipeUpView is present or swiped up, when I click outside of it, it will close/animate down.

Comment: What is a SwipeUpView? Why not use a BottomSheet? https://blog.mindorks.com/android-bottomsheet-in-kotlin

Comment: SwipeUpView is just a normal layout. But when im using a bottom sheet, that sheet is always visible on the screen? If so, its not what I want, what I want is not visible on the screen then when you do swipe up, it shows the layout with buttons.

Comment: You can hide it by settings the state:  `bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)`

Answer (score 0):

You could set a new onClick for the fragment when the view is inflated, and then set it back when the view is dismissed.

Comment: How? Main activity has 4 fragments under it, swipeUpView is inflated from Main Activity, how can I call the dismiss function on every fragment if swipeUpView method is from Main Activity?